# Rebinding SQL data to dropdown but keeping the hardcoded options from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, .net-4.5

I have a DropDownList with 3 hardcoded options in my aspx page which also has data from an SQL server appended to it (AppendDataBoundItems="true") from the code behind. What I would like to do is always keep those 3 hardcoded options but when a partial or full page reload happens that any new SQL data pulled from the DB will override the exsiting SQL databound info but leave the 3 hardcoded options intact.

ASPX Page Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlParentLocation" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Select Parent Location" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="None" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Unknown" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void ddlMediaList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Load existing locations for SelectedID
    ddlParentLocation.DataSource = SQLHelper.GetDataByQuery("SELECT LocationID, LocationName FROM dbo.vwLocations WHERE SectionID = '" + ddlMediaList.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'");
    ddlParentLocation.DataValueField = "LocationID";
    ddlParentLocation.DataTextField = "LocationName";
    ddlParentLocation.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is remember those list items before you do the binding. You can do it like this:

```
            List<ListItem> itemList = new List<ListItem>(ddl1.Items.Count);
            foreach (ListItem item in ddl1.Items)
            {
                itemList.Add(item);
            }
```

Then after binding you can add them back like this:

```
            foreach (ListItem item in itemList)
            {
                ddl1.Items.Add(item);
            }
```

You can use Insert instead of Add if you want them in the top of the list.

Comment: It seems that it would just be easier to hand code each option in then having to create lists and loop though everything.

Comment: If you have just one or two options than it might be a little easier. But using a loop you will be able to add more hard coded options (or remove existing ones) with no need to update this code as well, it will keep working correctly. That makes the code slightly more maintainable.